# SELECT MIN, MAX, AVG and current (for latest insert ID) value all together

Tags: mysql

I need to get GROUPed BY values,
but I need to see not a random price value (when I select price), but latest price value (price for a row with highest ID within this GROUP)

```
SELECT ID, price, 
       ROUND(AVG(price)), 
       MIN(price),
       MAX(price),
       ROUND((AVG(price)-MIN(price))/AVG(price) * 100) as differenceinprices 
FROM `m-orbitzone` 
WHERE dep = 'MOW' 
  AND returnornot = 1 
GROUP BY arv, date1, date2 
ORDER BY differenceinprices DESC LIMIT 1000



ID    price <--     ROUND(AVG(price))   MIN(price)  MAX(price)  differenceinprices
122841  834 816 534 834 35
122708  783 790 524 821 34
122754  766 796 529 815 34
28528   810 766 512 810 33
28529   799 765 512 799 33
122603  766 798 534 841 33
122848  766 794 529 810 33
122589  778 765 519 778 32
122591  778 768 519 778 32
122749  766 775 529 814 32
28527   752 749 512 773 32
122744  766 773 529 814 32
122843  766 771 529 802 31
```

Need 'price' to be latest price for this GROUP (row with highest ID)

May be need to do SELECT and then to do one more SELECT from result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT m.ID, price, 
       ROUND(AVG(price)), 
       MIN(price),
       MAX(price),
       ROUND((AVG(price)-MIN(price))/AVG(price) * 100) as differenceinprices 
FROM `m-orbitzone` m
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
   ID
   FROM
   `m-orbitzone` m
   WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `m-orbitzone` sm WHERE m.arv = sm.arv AND m.date1 = sm.date1 AND m.date2 = sm.date2)
) s ON m.ID = s.ID
WHERE dep = 'MOW' 
  AND returnornot = 1 
GROUP BY arv, date1, date2 
ORDER BY differenceinprices DESC LIMIT 1000
```

A good read about the topic is [this manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html).